From time to time: Unresolved reference for Kotlin extensions in Android Studio although everything is correct
After editing some Kotlin classes in my rather big project in Android Studio, I am receiving from time to time a Kotlin compile error (task compileDebugKotlin), of type "Unresolved Reference: <extension function>" for Kotlin extensions defined globally and imported into the sources I just changed.
Both sources, i.e. the extension property and the class using it are in the same module.
Example:
//Kotlin file ViewExtensions.kt
import android.view.View
...
var View.bVisibility: Boolean
    get() {
        return this.visibility == View.VISIBLE
    }
    set(visible) {
        this.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
...
// Some more extension properties/functions in same file

The problem appears only from time to time and suddenly after some source code changes, but I could not find any pattern so far, for typical changes causing it.
The source code is syntactically correct, because a full rebuild (without any further changes) typically solves the problem (but takes a lot of time due to the size of the project).
I can also navigate (Ctrl+Click) to the extension function/property, immediately after the compiler reports the error. So the function can be found by Android Studio, but not by the compiler.
Any idea what could be the reason, that the compiler cannot find the sources, and how I could avoid the full rebuild?
Proposals on how I can narrow down the problem are also welcome.

I just had the problem again. Making a trivial change (adding a blank) in the source code of the extension fixed the problem this time. I will check next time, if this always helps.
